# How can I create a separate admin route in react js?

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router-dom

I trying to create a reactjs app in where at the topmost layer there will be two routes **USER** and **ADMIN**. By default when the app loads for the very first time it should always load user login page (if the user is not logged in). And whenever admin tries to login they manually need to type `/admin` route to enter the admin login page. Can anyone help me with this kind of routing. I'm checking the user/admin logged in status with the help of local storage.

```
<Router>
    <Route path="/" component={User}/>
    <Route exact path="/admin" component={Admin}/>
</Router>
```

How can I modify these routes to meet my requirement?

Comment: What is the problem? Have you tried something?

Comment: Problem: admin login page will appear only by manually entering `/admin` route like localhost:3000/admin and in no other way. Every time any user coming to view the application will be able to see the user login page only.

Comment: Get a token from the server that differentiates when an user is admin or not.
If the user is not admin, then you could block the `/admin` route.

Comment: Is there any workaround with react routing?

Comment: Nope, because only your server knows who is client or admin. Either you could hardcode the id of the admin and check it, but that is not recommended.